# Trocar cor da caixa de um CheckBox

Tags: android

É possível trocar a cor da caixa de um CheckBox via programa (runtime)?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de trocar a cor branca da caixa em destaque na imagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa cor é definida pelo tema que você usa, portanto uma primeira saída seria alterar o tema em runtime - meio estranho, mas possível.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ...

    // chame setTheme antes de criar qualquer View

    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dark);

    // ...

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Se você quiser alterar o tema após a criação da `Activity`, você terá que recriar a atividade e informar o novo tema a ser usado.

Caso pareça muito ineficiente, você também pode alterar o `buttonTintList` do `CheckBox`. Para isso, basta chamar `CheckBox#setButtonTintList(ColorStateList)` e você altera como o CheckBox será desenhado em cada estado. Existe dois caminhos para criar um `ColorStateList`:

**Código**

```
private static final int[][] CHECK_BOX_STATES = new int[][] {
    new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // desabilitado
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked}, // marcado
    new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // desmarcado
    new int[] {} // default
};

private static final int[] CHECK_BOX_COLORS = new int[] {
    Color.GRAY,
    Color.CYAN,
    Color.MAGENTA,
    Color.MAGENTA
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ...

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_id);

    // limpa buttonTintList
    checkBox.setButtonTintList(null);
    checkBox.setButtonTintList(new ColorStateList(CHECK_BOX_STATES, CHECK_BOX_COLORS));

    // ...
}
```

**XML**

assets/checkbox_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="#ffff00" />

    <item android:state_checked="true"
            android:color="#00ffff" /> 

    <item android:state_checked="false"
            android:color="#ff00ff" />
</selector>
```

Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ...

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_id);

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(getAssets().open("checkbox_style.xml"), "UTF-8");

        checkBox.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(), parser));
    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Em nenhum dos dois casos consegui alterar definitivamente a cor do CheckBox. Via código a cor muda somente uma vez para cada estado (por exemplo: muda quando marca, mas quando desmarca não retorna a cor do estado desmarcado), já via XML o emulador lança uma exceção bizarra reclamando que a tag `item` precisar ter um atributo `android:color`.

Para mais informações olhe a documentação: [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html), [CompoundButton#setButtonTintList(ColorStateList)](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setButtonTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)), [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu utilizei a primeira parte de sua resposta. Como o usuário escolhe o tema q ele quer, não fica tão ineficiente. Obrigado